# Use OpenCV, cv2.videocapture in Kivy with Android - Python For Android

Tags: android, python, opencv, kivy, buildozer

I have been working for a few days, trying to use `cv2.VideoCapture()` in `python-for-android`. I'm using `Kivy` with `buildozer` to build `apk` for Android. Here is my code

```py
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
    import cv2


    class KivyCamera(Image):
        def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
            super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.capture = capture
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

        def update(self, dt):
            print 'hello'
            ret, frame = self.capture.read()
            print frame
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


    class CamApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
            self.my_camera = KivyCamera(capture=self.capture, fps=30)
            return self.my_camera

        def on_stop(self):
            #without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
            self.capture.release()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        CamApp().run()
```

This code is totally running on pc and successfully displaying the video feed, but if I build this to apk file using buildozer it will get crashed as soon as application launched.
Can someone help me to fix this issue??
Anyway If anyone have done this please comment..

This is the logcat from Android device:

```
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00018b00    /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+71)
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00505fc9  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 005069fb  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00506e0d  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0037a4fb  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0037aa71  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0037261d  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0037291b  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 003729ff  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0015cf2b  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
    08-14 10:05:16.807 16826-16826/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000603c5  /data/app/org.test.myapp-1/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so (PyCFunction_Call+144)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: How can I get it??

Comment: Refer to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#systemLogView

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I posted the stack trace above

Comment: @SaurabhThorat have you done this successfully??

Comment: This code runs but shows black screen with a white square in the lower left corner. Still no one find a solution? a week now i'm searching for a solution to this!

Comment: `self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` should be 0, right?