# Play Video Using OpenCV library with kivy and python-for-android on android

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

Try to play video using **OpenCV** library with **kivy** and python-for-android

Here is my attempt:

```
import os

import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture=None, fps=0, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture("/sdcard2/python-apk/2.mp4")
        print "file path exist :" + str(os.path.exists("/sdcard2/python-apk/1.mkv"))
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture("/sdcard2/python-apk/1.mkv")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        print str(os.listdir('/sdcard2/'))
        if ret:
            # convert it to texture
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.my_camera = KivyCamera(fps=30)
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        btn1 = Button(text="Hello")
        self.box.add_widget(btn1)
        # l = Label(text=cv2.__version__, font_size=150)
        # self.box.add_widget(l)
        self.box.add_widget(self.my_camera)
        return self.box

    def on_stop(self):
        # without this, app will not exit even if the window is closed
        # self.capture.release()
        pass

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

and In **bulldozer.spec** file

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,zip,mp4



# (list) Application requirements
requirements = plyer,kivy,opencv,numpy,pyjnius,ffmpeg, sqlite3, openssl
```

I am trying to play video using OpenCV **cv2.VideoCapture()** method, Above program working on desktop fine but when I build APK using `bulldozer` and run the app on the android phone I just get white screen only. I try to play **`.mp4`** or **`.mkv`** format, but in both cases, I get a white screen. What I Am doing wrong or where is my mistake ??

[image]

Here is my log file:

## **[Log File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l4nrew6ksy9nom/adb_log?dl=0)**

**Similar Question:**

[This question also don't have any answer yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659872/use-opencv-cv2-videocapture-in-kivy-with-android-python-for-android)

Comment: Downvote with any reason...please tell me any reason.

Comment: is there any reason you don't use video widget and `ffpyplayer` provider?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov for further processing with opencv

Comment: Do you have the same version of Android on the Phone as with the emulator you are using?

Comment: do you need to include any Codecs or allow access to codecs to play mp4 files in your app?

Comment: @johnashu I am trying to run on `htc one E9+ phone` and for mp4 I use mp4 extension check updated question